# Defining a user defined function in DynamicModule

Tags: dynamic, initialization

How can I define a user defined function within `DynamicModule`? For example, if

```
h[x_] := x^2
```

I want to find `h[2]`.

Comment: This question is not clear to me; can you give an extended example, please?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Some what like this. DynamicModule[{h[x_] := x^2}, h[2]] so that it can be deployed intp CDF.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience deploying to CDF (version 7), but I don't see anything to stop you from doing:

```
DynamicModule[{h},
 h[x_] := x^2;
 h[2]
]
```

> 4

If this fails perhaps you could explain in what way.

Comment: It works but if there are more than 1 user defined functions

Comment: @Jennifer then add them just like the first: `DynamicModule[{h, i, j}` ... `h[x_] := x^2; i[x_] := Sqrt @ x; j[x_] := Sin[x^4];  -- perhaps I still don't understand?

Comment: It shows error for this DynamicModule[{h, i, j}, h[x_] := x^2; i[x_] := Sqrt@x; 
 j[x_] := Sin[x^4];
 h[2], i[3], j[5]]

Comment: @Jennifer you need to watch your syntax more closely;  you accidentally are passing additional arguments to `DynamicModule`.  Try this instead: `DynamicModule[{h, i, j},
 h[x_] := x^2; i[x_] := Sqrt@x; j[x_] := Sin[x^4];
 {h[2], i[3], j[5]}
 ]`

Comment: Oh yes. Thanks. Now working